# JavaScript Encryption to access the json data url

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc, encryption, asp.net-web-api

The below script is used to access the json data from the web api. While i tried to access the data with the url "http://localhost:55506/api/Login/submit?username=" + uname + "&password=" + login.password + ""; it returns error with the variable uname. (**Undefined uname**)

But when i tried to access the same data with actual username & password (http://localhost:55506/api/Login/submit?username=raja&password=abc123).  It returns the table with correct data.

i want to display the user details in view page. so i used the script below in my view page

Thanks in advance for the help.

**View Page**

```
<script>

    $(function () {

        var entries = [];
        var dmJSON = "http://localhost:55506/api/Login/submit?username=" + uname + "&password=" + login.password + "";
        $.getJSON(dmJSON, function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (i, f) {
                var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.UserID + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.FirstName + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.LastName + "</td>" + "</tr>"
                $(tblRow).appendTo("#entrydata tbody");

            });

        });

    });
</script>
```

**My Controller**

```
  public ActionResult Index(Login login)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) // Check the model state for any validation errors
        {
            string uname = "";
            uname = login.username;
            string pword = "";
            pword = login.password;
            string url = "http://localhost:55506/api/Login/submit?username=" + uname + "&password=" + pword + "";
            System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
            var responseData = responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<LoginResult>>(responseData);
            if (responseData.Contains("True"))
            {
                return View("Show", login); // Return the "Show.cshtml" view if user is valid
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Invalid Username or Password";
                return View(); //return the same view with message "Invalid Username or Password"
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }
        return View();
    }
```

**My Model**

```
     public class Login
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Username is required")] // make the field required
    [Display(Name = "username")]  // Set the display name of the field
    public string username { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
    [Display(Name = "password")]
    public string password { get; set; }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Download and include this plugin

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/md5.js">
```

and use like

```
if(CryptoJS.MD5($("#txtOldPassword").val())) != oldPassword) {

}

//Following lines shows md5 value
//var hash = CryptoJS.MD5("Message");
//alert(hash);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should console.log your variable and you'd see the error.

Your double quotes at the end aren't appending a quote to the string.

More information would be useful but to try and solve all scenarios try this:

```
'http://localhost:55506/api/Login/submit?username=' + "'" + uname + "'" + '&password=' + "'" + login.password + "'"
```

What's happening with your current string is the last set of double quotes are being escaped out, Javascript thinks your protecting the empty space from being expanded, which it happily does. I'm guessing you wanted the username and password to be surrounded by quotes in the final variable but to be expanded as the values they represent.

I replaced the double quotes with single, using the double quotes to protect the characters I wanted to be literal.

You should add a console.log or alert to show you exactly what the variable is once it's done:

```
var entries = [];
    var dmJSON = "your string"
console.log (dmJSON)
//the rest of your code
```

You can and should take the log out afterwards, but it will show you exactly what is being put in the variable.

All that being said, sending the information over an unencrypted get request isn't secure at all. The information will be plainly printed in the Url. A post request should be used at the very least, and sent over https is preferable.

Comment: There is an error when i used console.log(dmJSON) .... The error is Undefined : uname.   It compares the uname with <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>....kindly suggest me to solve this issues. Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like your variable isn't being passed into the form. I'd have to see more of your code (specifically how you are calling the function and where the variables are coming from).

Do this to test and see if the URL and jQuery are working correctly, manually name your variables in your script.
    var uname = "raj";
    var loginpassword = "abc123";

You'll have to remove the period to set the variable, do the same in your dmJSON string. Then test your function. If that works you know your function is fine and the problem is passing in the values.

Comment: Hi @jcalton88 . i tried to access by defining my variable manually,it works fine. the code i given above is my full code . the variable **uname** is declared in controller. But it still shows the error on my passing variable. Kindly suggest.

Comment: In your script do you mean to call login.password instead of pword?

Comment: i used to check that..whether it works or not. Even the one also not working

Comment: You should retag the question as MVC or ASP so that its seen by more people. I'm not as knowledgable in that area.